# how to schedule an expiration time when the last user leaves the conference asterisk

Tags: asterisk, blacklist

I am working in ubuntu 9.10. I am using asterisk and meetme.conf. I would like to ask what should I write in extensions.conf for expiring a conference call when the last participant left?
How can I add on a blacklist an ip if a user tries to enter multiple time on in conference room, but doesn't know the pin number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if you can have the meetme end when the LAST person leaves, but you can hav it end when the LEADER/ADMIN leaves using the a option